# How to define a locale relative to the url in kraken.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, routes, kraken.js

I've follow the kraken.js example to get i18n for my website.
So now, 1 template file is rendered in each set-up language.

For example : index.dust can be rendered in French, English and Dutch.
What I'm trying to achieve now is, if a user goes to :

```
<site>/accueil -> website in french
<site>/home -> website in english
```

And so on.

The kraken.js example relies on cookies. But if the user comes for the first time, the actual config will render a page in french (default locale) even if he came with an english url.

I thought about an array for each route:locale (/accueil, /home, /startseite, etc) to define the locality but this is far from a clean code PLUS I will have to manually edit the array for every page added.

Does anyone have a better idea ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I used the array that I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a middleware or param handler assign the locale from the parameter in the URL, rather than using a cookie.